# Adding set lists of future dates to rows in a SQL query

Tags: sql, vertica

So I am doing a cohort analysis for customers, where a cohort is a group of people who started using the product in the same month. I then keep track of each cohort's total use for every subsequent month up till present time.

For example, the first "cohort month" is January 2012, then I have "use months" January 12, Feb 12, March 12, ..., March 17(current month). One column is "cohort month", and another is "use month". This process repeats for every subsequent cohort month. The table looks like:

```
Jan 12 | Jan 12  
Jan 12 | Feb 12  
...   
Jan 12 | Mar 17  
Feb 12 | Feb 12  
Feb 12 | Mar 12  
...  
Feb 12 | Mar 17  
...  
Feb 17 | Feb 17  
Feb 17 | Mar 17  
Mar 17 | Mar 17
```

The problem arises because I want to do forecasting for one year out for both existing and future cohorts.
That means for the Jan 12 cohort, I want to do prediction for April 17 to Mar 18. 
I also want to do predictions for the April 17 cohort (which doesn't exist yet) from April 17 to Mar 18. And so on till predictions for the Mar 18 cohort in Mar 18.
I can handle the predictions, don't worry about that.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to add in this list of (April 17 .. Mar 17) in the "use month" column before every cohort switches. 
I also need to add in cohorts April 17 to Mar 18, and have the applicable parts of this list of (April 17 ... Mar 17) for each of these future cohorts.

So I want the table to look like:

```
Jan 12 | Jan 12  
Jan 12 | Feb 12  
...   
Jan 12 | Mar 17  
Jan 12 | Apr 17  
..    
Jan 12 | Mar 18  
Feb 12 | Feb 12  
Feb 12 | Mar 12  
...  
Feb 12 | Mar 17  
Feb 12 | Apr 17  
...  
Feb 12 | Mar 18  
...    
...    
Feb 17 | Feb 17  
Feb 17 | Mar 17    
...  
Feb 17 | Mar 18  
Mar 17 | Mar 17    
...  
Mar 17 | Mar 18
```

I know the first solution to come to mind is to do a create a list of all dates Jan 12 to Mar 18, cross join it to itself, and then left outer join to the current table I have (where cohort / use months range from Jan 12 to Mar 17). However, this is not scalable.

Is there a way I can just iteratively add in this list of the months of the next year?

I am using HP Vertica, could use Presto or Hive if absolutely necessary

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the query here below to create a temporary table out of nothing, and join it with the rest of your query. You can't do anything in a procedural manner in SQL, I'm afraid. You won't be able to get away without a CROSS JOIN. But here, you limit the CROSS JOIN to the generation of the first-of-month pairs that you need.

Here goes:

```
WITH
-- create a list of integers from 0 to 100 using the TIMESERIES clause
i(i) AS (
SELECT dt::DATE - '2000-01-01'::DATE
FROM ( 
          SELECT '2000-01-01'::DATE +   0 
UNION ALL SELECT '2000-01-01'::DATE + 100
) d(d)
TIMESERIES dt AS '1 day' OVER(ORDER BY d::TIMESTAMP)
)
,
-- limits are Jan-2012 to the first of the current month plus one year
month_limits(month_limit) AS (
          SELECT '2012-01-01'::DATE
UNION ALL SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH'),12)
)
-- create the list of possible months as a CROSS JOIN of the i table
-- containing the integers and the month_limits table, using ADD_MONTHS()
-- and the smallest and greatest month of the month limits
,month_list AS (
SELECT
  ADD_MONTHS(MIN(month_limit),i) AS month_first
FROM month_limits CROSS JOIN i
GROUP BY i
HAVING ADD_MONTHS(MIN(month_limit),i) <= (
  SELECT MAX(month_limit) FROM month_limits
  )
)
-- finally, CROSS JOIN the obtained month list with itself with the
-- filters needed.
SELECT
  cohort.month_first AS cohort_month
, use.month_first    AS use_month
FROM month_list AS cohort
CROSS JOIN month_list AS use
WHERE use.month_first >= cohort.month_first
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```